# Table got dropped from phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a PHP application which is on a production server and it`s meant to register users to some services. It has two forms which registers a user in a different table from my database.

Problem is that today one of the tables disappeared and I was able to restore it from a backup. But this dose`t get rid of the problem.

How do I investigate this in order to determine how that table got lost and most likely dropped by some bot or something.

How would you proceed in a situation like this?

Comment: check your access logs and you may have been hacked by not using a prepared statement; it could be anything.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

Have a working backup of the system, and restore the files from it.
An undelete tool might help, if you deleted the db very recently (and ideally, if you unplugged the computer right afterward).
As for doing it with MySQL, though...on all systems i'm aware of, no. MySQL tables are files in the server's data directory, and dropping a table deletes those files. Once they're gone, they're gone, and only the methods above can get them back. A database is a directory of those files, and dropping it deletes the whole directory.

Check this free software

http://www.majorgeeks.com/Restoration_d4474.html

More information here - http://emaillenin.blogspot.com/2010/11/recover-accidentally-deleted-mysql.html

Comment: I have already restored my database from a backup. How do I investigate how that table got dropped?

Comment: SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%log_file%'

try this quary and it will show you where are the log files and investigate on those.

Answer (score 0):

If your tables got dropped, find out what mysql users have privileges to drop a table (there shouldn't be many) and what services log in with that user credentials.
Maybe you have a web form with a php backend that doesn't clean up (escape) input, so you were maybe open to sql injection.
In that case, you could check you webserver access log.